# Nginx: How to limit request rate based on user agent

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

Trying to get the following behavior working in nginx

A default rate limit of 1r/s for each ip when using a browser.
A rate limit of 10r/s for bing and google spiders.
Reject bad bots.

Unfortunately google doesn't publish ip addresses for googlebot so I'm limited to useragent.

So far this gets close:

```
http { 
  # Rate limits
  map $http_user_agent $uatype {
    default 'user';
    ~*(google|bing|msnbot) 'okbot';
    ~*(slurp|nastybot) 'badbot';
  }

  limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;
  limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=two:10m rate=10r/s;

  ...

  server {
    ...

    location / {
      if ($uatype == 'badbot) {
        return 403;
      }

      limit_req zone=one burst=5 nodelay;
      if ($uatype != 'user') {
        limit_req zone=two burst=10 nodelay;
      }

      ...
    }

  ...
  }
}
```

BUT - 'if' isn't allowed to do this.

$ nginx -t

nginx: [emerg] "limit_req" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

There are so many untested suggestions on nginx forums, most do not even pass configtest.

One that looks promising is [Nginx Rate Limiting by Referrer?](https://serverfault.com/questions/547490/nginx-rate-limiting-by-referrer) -- Downside of that version is that all of the configuration is repeated for each different limit (I have many rewrite rules)

Anyone got something good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't dynamize this way, limit request module doesn't support this.

The link you found is probably the only way to achieve this. Use `include` directive to "avoid" repeating your configuration.

But what if a thirdparty crawler suddenly impersonate a *goodbot* user agent ?

Comment: > But what if a thirdparty crawler suddenly impersonate a goodbot user agent ? -- totally agree - terrible that google doesn't publish a ip list. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @AliW Interestingly, [tengine](http://tengine.taobao.org/document/http_limit_req.html) which is the chinese fork of nginx developed by alibaba seems to have better support for these cases.

Comment: In my error.log I see a line: 
2022/02/08 10:00:55 [error] 25833#25833: *150390 limiting requests, excess: 20.855 by zone "mylimit", client: 34.91.221.177, server: _, request: [MORE HERE]
How can I add the user-agent in the erorr.log print?

Answer (score 3):

Today I was able to implement rate limiting on a user agent base; try this:

```
map $http_user_agent $bad_bot {
    default 0;
    (foo|bar) 1;
}

map $http_user_agent $nice_bot {
    default "";
    (baz|qux) 1;
}

limit_req_zone $nice_bot zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;
limit_req_status 429;

server {
    ...
    location / {
        limit_req zone=one nodelay;
        if ($badbot) {
            return 403;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this limit all IPs that use the same user agent, or will it limit each IP that uses the user agent separately?

Comment: We are doing something similar, but not getting anything close to our "rate" across many IPs that are DDOSing us.